# How to write specific text from text file to textbox?

Tags: c#, file

I'd like to ask how could I write a textbox-specific text from a textfile? In this case, I'm looking for rows containing "***" and I want to list the row above.
I try this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.IO;

using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace mise2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private String filePath_output = string.Empty;
    
    private String filePath_input = string.Empty;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox2.AutoSize = true;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

        openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\";


        openFileDialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;


        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            filePath_input = openFileDialog.FileName;
            this.textBox1.Text = filePath_input;
        }

        
        List<String> lines = new List<String>();
        TextReader sr = File.OpenText(filePath_input);

        TextWriter sw = File.CreateText(textBox2.ToString());
        Int32 ri1 = 0;
        String line1 = "";
       
     
        {
            line1 = sr.ReadLine();
            lines.Add(line1);

            if (line1.IndexOf(@"***") != -1)
            {

                if (ri1 != 0)
                {
                    line1 = lines[ri1 - 1];
                   

                }

            }

            ri1 = ri1 + 1;

        }

        sr.Close();
        sw.Close();

        lines.Clear();


        textBox2.Text = filePath_output;
    }
}
}
```

writing to a file is not a problem I did that via streamwriter but once it's a textbox I don't even get anything started that I have the wrong way

Comment: Is it due to copy & paste or does the code actually lack a loop here? As is, you are only ever reading the first line of the file.

Comment: about copy and paste

Comment: can i use streamwriter with textbox?

Comment: `TextWriter sw = File.CreateText(textBox2.ToString());` are you aware of what this line _actually_ does? (Spoiler: What it _not_ does is open a stream to write _into_ the textbox.)

Comment: yes it is about file but a dont know how to write to textbox a I want to move closer my problem

Comment: `TextBox` has the [`Text`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.text?view=netcore-3.1) property. You'll probably want to use that.

Comment: @Fildor OP knows:  `this.textBox1.Text = filePath_input;`

Comment: @mcalex but he doesn't apply that knowledge consistently. So, without intent to offend anybody, I am suspecting a lot of copy & paste instead of knowledge.

Comment: @Fildor you're right my knowledge isn't like that that's why I'm asking here but perhaps that's what you got

Comment: So, do you want to have a text in textbox2 or do you want to write to file which is given by a path that is the content of textbox2? What I am getting from the code is that after your code has executed you want a path, that is the line above "***" in the file denoted by textbox1 in textbox2?

Comment: i would like to write to textbox

Comment: In that case, you might want to break that code down into several pieces ( ie functions) : 1. Get the filename of the file to read from 2. read that file to get the desired text 3. Write desired text to textbox2

Comment: In the selected file that lists in textbox1, so I want to get a line from it above the line that contains "***" and I want to inscribe that specific line in textbox2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of the event handler is quite alright, you are getting a path from user. I'd factor that out into a separate function.

Now, let's assume we have that path in `filepath_input` and now we get to the problem:

```
private string FindLineAboveAsterisks(string path)
{
     using TextReader sr = File.OpenText(path);
     return FindLineAboveAsterisks(sr);
}

private string FindLineAboveAsterisks(TextReader reader)
{
     string result = reader.ReadLine(); // Read 1st line
     string line = string.Empty;
     while ( result is object && (line = reader.ReadLine()) is object ) // Read to EOF
     {
         if (line.Contains("***"))
         {
             return result;
         }
         else
         {
              result = line;
         }
     }
     return string.Empty;
}
```

And finally you can set the textbox2 with the result:

```
 textBox2.Text = FindLineAboveAsterisks(filepath_input);
```

Comment: one more question, how do I list all the values? while I end up with the first value true

Comment: If there are more than 1 line that you want to return, then you could append to a StringBuilder instead of returning immediately and after the loop return it's string. I'll see if I can come up with an example later on.